# backbone loaded with requirejs shim but still Backbone undefined error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, amd

I've read many answers and followed steps I could ( seems right to me) but still DevTools shows `Backbone is not defined.` error.

Here's how I use requirejs shim.

```
<script data-main="js/subject_main.js" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

**subject_main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        bootstrap: '../libs/bootstrap.min',
        jquery:     '../libs/jquery',
        underscore: '../libs/underscore',
        backbone:   '../libs/backbone',
        text:       '../libs/text',
        json2:      '../libs/json2',
        templates:   '../../templates'
    },
    shim: {
        'boostrap':{
          deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }            
    }

});

require(['subjects', 'json2'], function(app) {
    app.initialize();
});
```

**subjects.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'subject_router'], function($, _, Backbone, router) {
    return {
        initialize: function() {
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    };
});
```

**subject_router**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/subject_item_model',
    'collections/subjects_collection',
    'views/subject_view'
],function($, _, Backbone) {              

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({ ... });

 return new AppRouter();
});
```

Chrome DevTools shows following sequence (order ) of scripts - 
[image]

As you can see, backbone is loaded at very end. I don't know what's going wrong and where.

Comment: How do you get "Backbone is not defined"? Does it just show up in the console with a file name and line number? (If so, where is this location in the code you've shown us?) Does it appear because you type ``Backbone`` at the console and the interpreter can't interpret it?

Comment: @Louis it appears in `subject_router.js` on line where I try to create a router. Network tab in DevTools shows router is loaded first before backbone.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but you left a t out of 'bootstrap' in your code.

Comment: @MrLister Yea.. that was a typo error. Anyway solved this issue. I completely skipped shim config of requirejs by replacing backbone and underscore with their AMD versions.

Answer (score 0):

backbone.js or underscore.js look fine to me here, and indeed they are being loaded!

The 404s in your dev tool are referring to the source mapping files (underscore.min.map). You might want to look at this post: [Missing Javascript ".map" file for Underscore.js when loading ASP.NET web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429625/missing-javascript-map-file-for-underscore-js-when-loading-asp-net-web-page).

PS: In your subject_router code you have a mismatch on the arguments passed in to the module function.

Comment: If by "mismatch" you mean the number of arguments declared, this is no problem at all. Otherwise, what mismatch are you seeing?

Comment: Yes, it would not create a problem in this case... but not a good practice. Just pointed it out in case you did not notice it. :)

Comment: Yea I solved that map error by adding those files for development purpose.