# Angularjs app showing underscore-min.map 404 (Not Found) and Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined fo.min.js

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, underscore.js, source-maps

I am using underscore for check box selections in Angularjs, till now it is working fine but suddenly I am getting the following error.

```
GET http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/underscore-min.map 404 (Not Found) testDashboard.do:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined fo.min.js?v=1_1_31:106(anonymous function) fo.min.js?v=1_1_31:106(anonymous function)
```

I have got reference to fix this at https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1477. But even after changing to underscore.min.map,  I am getting similar error . How can I fix this error?

```
GET http://localhost/dashboard2/js/d3angular/underscore.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

The following are the directives that I have included in my angular js application :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'nvd3', 'smartTable.table', 'snap', 'ui.tree', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);
```

The following are the relevant js and css files I have included :

```
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/Smart-Table.debug.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>

<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/snap.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular-snap.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard2/js/d3angular/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard2/js/controllers.js"></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></SCRIPT>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>




 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/nv.d3.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/angular-slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/d3styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/smartTable.css" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard2/css/angular-snap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard2/css/angular-ui-tree.min.css">
<link href="/css/ms-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Missing source maps isn't usually a problem. I would focus on the `Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined fo.min.js` error. Look at fo.js and see what it's trying to call `notify()` on. Is it something that is injected? If it is, is it annotated properly so that it can be minified?

Comment: Surprisingly I did not include any fo.min.js at all in my application. I don't know from which included js files this fo.min.js is being called. I am editing my question with the js files and directives I have included in my angular js application. If this information helps you to identify my problem please suggest me further. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Javascript ".map" file for Underscore.js when loading ASP.NET web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429625/missing-javascript-map-file-for-underscore-js-when-loading-asp-net-web-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In project find underscore.min.map file and rename to underscore-min.map or use link http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.map